# How can a TinyMCE modal return formatted/visual text?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am trying to customize the behavior of an editor button in a plugin. On click, it opens a modal where the user can input some text. On confirmation, I want to wrap this text into code tags. But I don't want to take this text as if it comes from a text editor, I want to handle it as visual text. This means, I want to preserve any formatting (whitespaces and linebreaks) but not accept any other tags besides the code tags that I add afterward.

```
function showDialog() {
    var win = ed.windowManager.open({
            title: "Insert code",
            body: {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'code',
                multiline: true,
                minWidth: ed.getParam("code_dialog_width", 600),
                minHeight: ed.getParam("code_dialog_height", Math.min(tinymce.DOM.getViewPort().h - 200, 500)),
                spellcheck: false,
                style: 'direction: ltr; text-align: left'
            },
            onSubmit: function(e) {
                ed.focus();

                ed.undoManager.transact(function() {
                    ed.insertContent('<code>' + e.data.code + '</code>');
                });

                ed.selection.setCursorLocation();
                ed.nodeChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First i'd wrap that function in  tags and make sure to initiate the function by adding showDialog() at the end of that function so the DOM knows to call the function. and with wordpress's content filter its going to add spaces no matter what unless you disable the content filter from auto populating format. if you go to a site like https://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/ and copy your code into that and minify the spaces you should be able to include it in your text(not Visual) tab in MCE. That being said its really bad practice to run functional code in MCE you're better off making a separate page / Post template for it.